# AngularJS ng-cloak type strategy for scope elements that load remotely?

Tags: angularjs

`ng-cloak` is great for delaying showing elements until compilation is complete.

Is there some equivalent (or a strategy) for hiding elements while data is loaded from the server?

Simple example:

```
<span>Name: {{item.name}}</span>
```

`ng-cloak` will make sure this is hidden until `item.name` is loaded in. But if `item.name` is loaded by the controller, e.g. from a REST API, then this will first show as "Name: " and then later flash to "Name: John". Controller snippet below:

```
$scope.item = Item.get({item:"1234"});
```

There also may be different items, loaded in serial or parallel:

```
$scope.item1 = Item.get({item:"1234"});
$scope.item2 = Item.get({item:"6789"});
```

Is there a "native-angular" approach for this? If not, what is the best strategy? Is it to simply have a `$scope.ready` flag set to false and have `ng-show="ready"` and then when the controller feels everything is loaded, to do `$scope.ready = true;`? Is there some standardized approach?

For example (using async lib):

```
$scope.ready = false;
async.parallel([
    function(cb) {
      Item.get({item:"1234"}, function(item){$scope.item1 = item; cb();});
    },
    function(cb) {
      Item.get({item:"6789"}, function(item){$scope.item2 = item; cb();});
    }
],function(err) {
    $scope.ready = true;
});
```

Comment: one option is you can use `resolve` in routing and template won't load until all promises returned

Comment: @charlietfl that sounds rather elegant. Can you add a link to some docs on it? Thanks!

Comment: https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-resolve. Quick well done overview. See $routeProvider docs for more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ngCloak` is really only useful on the initial page load.

for all other cases, I recommend simple `ngShow`/`ngHide`/`ngIf`

```
<span ng-show="ready">Name: {{item.name}}</span>
```

Comment: So you go for the ng-show page-wide approach like what I listed in the last example above? Any standardized approaches to it?

Comment: `ngShow` and `ngHide` change `display:none!important` whereas `ngIf` will remove the element from the DOM entirely.  This can affect visual placement of other elements on the page until the hidden elements are shown.

Comment: I went down the directive route, really nifty... but it works only 50% of the time for reasons unknown! I will have to open up a new question for it